# Add user to AWS Identity Pool automatically after login through Google Federated Identity into User Pool?

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, google-signin, federated-identity, aws-userpools

I am building a web app that hosts authentication security using AWS Cognito. I am having the users sign in through a google login page, which then adds that instance of login automatically to a configured AWS User Pool. I am doing this through this endpoint:

`https://your_domain/login?response_type=token&client_id=your_app_client_id&redirect_uri=your_callback_url`

and getting a response back that looks like:

`https://www.example.com/#id_token=123456789tokens123456789&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer`

How do I use this to then automatically add the user to a configured AWS Identity Pool? Do I then get credentials back from the Identity Pool allowing access to services like S3 and DynamoDB, and if so how do I do that?

The documentation is very confusing, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this without a library then you have to pass that token to cognito identity pool and exchange it for temporary access key and secret key. I would suggest you use a library like AWS-Amplify to manage your authentication needs. The library handles token refreshing as well.

Here is the documentation for Amplify: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#social-provider-federation